# How to provide various users access to private git repo without providing a specific username

Tags: git, github, terraform

I am setting up a private terraform repo and was planning to use the following format for accessing the repo via SSH:

`"git@USERNAME.github.com:USERNAME/my_private_repo.git"`

However, I was wondering if there is a way that I can set this up such that I do not need to add a specific USERNAME each time one of the various user's wants to access a module. So something like this:

`"git@github.com/my_private_repo.git"`

or

`"https://github.com/my_organization/my_private_repo.git"`

In the second case I would need a solution that doesn't lead to prompting for the password as it needs to authenticate automatically.

I was reading [here](https://wahlnetwork.com/2020/08/11/using-private-git-repositories-as-terraform-modules/) that this can be done using https, an oauth token, and dynamic git configuration. Essentially he says he generates a token and then substitutes it into the URL by adding the following into the `.gitconfig`:

```
[url "https://oauth2:TOKEN@github.com"]
    insteadOf = https://github.com
```

Would this work for multiple users? Would they each need to know the token and store it somewhere, or is there a better/more secure way of dealing with the token across many users?

Comment: Well, there is a way I am actually used to and that is by using SSH keys. That requires `ssh-agent` running in the background but it seems less complex than what you are trying to do.

Comment: This is really more of a Git authentication question than TF question, but yes: there are methods of authenticating Git for teams, service accounts, etc. As for storing and accessing, that would be more of a pipeline+secrets management question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would this work for multiple users

No, a token is generally tied to a user (except deploy token tied to a repository)

SSH would be preferable:

```
[url "git@github.com:"]
    insteadOf = https://github.com/
```

That implies each user has register its public SSH key to their GitHub profile.

Comment: Yes this worked, thanks. One question though, is there any benefit to me defining the `source = "https://github.com/my_organization/my_private_repo.git"` and then using the `insteadOf` to switch it to ssh, or should I just code the source using the ssh pre-fix and skip the insteadOf part altogether?

Comment: @SteveAhlswede If you can use SSH directly, that would be easier: no git config necessary.